# Image upload in react-native app to s3 using node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I want to upload images through my merchant app build using react-native,node and express to AWS S3 and to fetch the same in my react native customer  app.
Is it possible to get a url after uploading through my merchant app and to use the same in my client app.
I've to apply this functionality in my application .

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to write the path of an image to a database on the server side. And then query the database for the uri when you want to fetch it.

Comment: Can you share me the code of how to upload and fetch the image from s3 in react native.